# Load Mask not working in extjs

Tags: extjs

Load mask not working, I set property `loadMask: true` and I still have the same problem, I cant see loadmask control, this grid was added inside ui layout, also I used `loadMask` function and I still have the same problem, please advise .

```
     gridHistory = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
         id: "gvHistory",
         ddGroup: 'gridDDGroup',
         store: gridStore,
         renderTo: 'HistoryPanel',
         layout: 'fit',
         columns: cols,
         enableDragDrop: true,
         stripeRows: true,
         pageSize: 25,
         header: false,
         loadMask: true,
         autoScroll: true,
         autoExpandColumn: 'Position_ID',
         height: resolveHistoryGridHeight(),
         forceFit: true,
         autoFill: true,
         iconCls: 'icon-grid',
         tbar: [{
             tooltip: 'Reload',
             iconCls: 'reload',
             iconMask: true, 
             handler: function () { getPositionsHistory(); }
         }, '-', {
             tooltip: 'Clear',
             iconCls: 'clear',
             iconMask: true, 
             handler: function () { Clear(); }
         }
         , '-', {
             xtype: 'checkbox',
             name: 'field1',
             boxLabel: 'Draw Track',
             id: 'cb_draw_track',
             handler: function () { if (this.checked) { drawTrack(); } }
         }],
         selModel: new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel({ singleSelect: false })
     });
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. surrounding your code snippets in <pre><code> tags will makes the code easier to read. (click on the orange help icon near the editor window to know more)

Comment: the load mask will only show **whilst the underlying store is requesting records from the server**. If you've loaded the data into the store before the grid is rendered, or if the store data is inline then it won't show the load mask

Comment: Jaitsu's comment is spot-on. Can you show us your store declaration?

Comment: var gridStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
            fields: fields,
            data: myData,
            root: 'records'});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the `loadMask` config is not having any effect is because your grid's data is defined inline.

```
var gridStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({ fields: fields, data: myData, root: 'records'});
```

By this, I mean that you are not loading your data from the server. The load mask will only show on the grid when it is making a request to the server, and this is why no load mask is being displayed.

You can change your store's data property to a URL instead, and return a JSON response from the server but I wouldn't advise this if you can use inline data instead.

Comment: thank you Mr. jaitsu, but acctually i dont understand what do you mean of loading data inline ?? .... actually i have this grid on my home page and i load data from server, i have dynamic data as im using SQL server, im using webservice to retreive this data, could you please explain to me what do you mean of inline data ? by the way, im using    Ext.ComponentMgr.get("gvHistory").store.loadData(myData); to load my grid